# Remove stylings from button in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a button with these stylings when it´s on hover:

```
      a.button:hover, a.comment-reply-link:hover, #commentform #submit:hover, .submit:hover, input[type=submit]:hover, input.button:hover, button.button:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ff5911;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ff5911), to(#ee3700));
/* Saf4+, Chrome */

background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff5911, #ee3700);
/* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */

background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5911, #ee3700);
/* FF3.6+ */

background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff5911, #ee3700);
/* IE10 */

background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff5911, #ee3700);
/* Opera 11.10+ */

background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff5911, #ee3700);
}
```

As Im working in a child theme in Wordpress, I can not just remove the the code, I need to override it.

I have tried with:

```
   background-image: none;
   background-color:transparent;
```

and I have tried to change all the the background-images tags to (to bottom, transparent, transparent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `!important` flag on your style. This should override any other style that was put on the element anywhere else.

```
background-image: none !important;
```

[Here's](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/) a reference showing some of the rules behind CSS valuation - it gets pretty tricky. The `!important` flag is generally not recommended, but sometimes you just need to do it.

Comment: I tried to add this to style.css in my child theme. http://jsfiddle.net/F6rcm/

You can see the problem live here: http://oliver.kaspertoxvig.dk/

Comment: Please invest 15 minutes to read up on CSS specifity. It will make your work much easier - and you probably don't need `!important`. I find this a good explanation: http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/